# Angular: Nome do modulo não é carregado na tag html ngApp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, bootstrap

Estou fazendo um teste basico em angular que lê um json simples e exibe na tela.

O meu problema é que quando coloco no nome do módulo o nome do módulo na tag ng-app todas as funções do angular param de funcionar.

Inspecionando o código do chrome encontrei o erro:

> Failed to instantiate module MeuModulo due to: Error:
>   [$injector:nomod] Module 'MeuModulo' is not available! You either
>   misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a
>   module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second
>   argument.

NOTA: Tentei executar este html direto no browser e no Tomcat, nenhum dos dois mudou o resultado.

Estou iniciando nos estudos de angular e não tenho ideia do que pode estar faltando.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="MeuModulo">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AngularJS - EX 3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="teste3.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MeuController">
    <p><b>Lista:</b></p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="agenda in registros">
            {{agenda.nome}} - <em>{{agenda.email}}</em>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Arquivo JS:

```
//teste3.js
var myModulo = angular.module('MeuModulo', ['ngRoute']);
myModulo.controller('MeuController',funcion($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('teste3.json')
    .then(funcion(retorno){
      $scope.registros = retorno.data;
    });
});
```

JSON utilizado:

```
[
  { "nome":"Rafael", "email":"rafael@hotmail.com" },
  { "nome":"Yara", "email":"yara@hotmail.com" },
  { "nome":"Renan", "email":"renan@hotmail.com" },
  { "nome":"Thaisa", "email":"thaisa@hotmail.com" },
  { "nome":"Naiara", "email":"naiara@hotmail.com" }
]
```

**Resultado:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="MeuModulo">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AngularJS - EX 3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="teste3.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MeuController">
    <p><b>Lista:</b></p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="agenda in registros">
            {{agenda.nome}} - <em>{{agenda.email}}</em>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: você está iniciando o módulo errado, o certo seria var myModulo = angular.module('MeuModulo', ['ngRoute']);

Comment: a foi um erro de digitação, mas corrigir e mesmo assim não funciona.

Answer (score 2):

cara, deu pau porque tu colocou modulo, e é module.

tenta fazer assim:

```
angular.module('MeuModulo', ['ngRoute']);
angular.module('MeuModulo').controller('MeuController',funcion($scope, $http)
```

Comment: Veja também que os `function` estão escrito errado.

Comment: Não funcionou, o meu problema é quando coloco a tag ng-app o angular funciona, mas se coloco ng-app="MeuModulo" (ou qualquer nome) ele para de funcionar.
Mesmo quando faço algo mais facil quanto isso:
<html ng-app="X">
<body>
<nav ng-click="$event.preventDefault()">
<a href="#" ng-click="escolha='Home'">Home</a>
</nav>
<p>Olha ai sua escola: {{escolha}}</p>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</html>